# ticklabels for polaraxis plot

Tags: axis, angle, polar

How can I add ^\circ to all xticklabels in a polaraxis plot? The following attempt adds a lot of filling zeros:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\y{50}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
            xtick={0,30,...,330},
            xticklabel={${\tick}^\circ$},
            xticklabel style={anchor=\tick+180},
            ytick={-30,-20,...,20},
            grid=both,
            ymin=-\y, 
            ymax=30,
            xmin=0, 
            xmax=360,
            y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+\y}, % done in order to get negative values on y axis
            y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-\y}, % normalize previous step
        ]
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Also, is it possible to have the yticklabels on the "yaxis" instead?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it is sufficient to convert the ticks to integers.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\y{50}
    \begin{polaraxis}[
            xtick={90,120,...,450},
            xticklabel={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mytick}{\tick}${\mytick}^\circ$},
            xticklabel style={anchor=\tick+180},
            ytick={-30,-20,...,20},
            grid=both,
            ymin=-\y, 
            ymax=30,
            xmin=90, 
            xmax=450,
            y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+\y}, % done in order to get negative values on y axis
            y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-\y}, % normalize previous step
        ]
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I was too slow but did it just with `\pgfmathprintnumber`

Comment: Thanks! Is it easy to solve the second question as well? "Also, is it possible to have the yticklabels on the "yaxis" instead?"

Comment: @user2978680 Yes, of course.